# Jenkins Global properties not updated immediately

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a global variable which is stored in jenkins `Global properties`

[image]

This variable is updated using [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) v1.3

[image]

```
import jenkins.model.*

nodes = Jenkins.instance.globalNodeProperties
nodes.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
envVars = nodes[0].envVars

target = envVars['testVar'].toInteger() + 1
envVars['testVar'] = target.toString()
```

The groovy script adds 1 to `testVar` whenever the job gets executed.

However, I couldn't get the updated value in the next build step.

[image]

As you can see in the following execution result, the value of `testVar` got by powershell is the old value.

[image]

Is it possible to get the newly updated value of `testVar` with powershell in the next build step?

Comment: Thought of using a counter for that?

Comment: The counter is used only for demonstration purpose.